# Was the Athanasian Creed ever translated into Koine Greek? If so, where can I find the text?

Tags: resource-request, greek, latin, athanasian-creed

I am aware that it was most likely originally composed in Latin (this is why it is highly unlikely that St. Athanasius himself wrote it) but has anyone ever tried translating it into Koine Greek?

If so, where would I be able to find the text?

Comment: I had a good look but was unable to find any Greek text.

Answer (score -1):

After a lot of searching, I found out that the Athanasian Creed does, in fact, exist in several Koine Greek versions. Here is one version of it:

1. Όποιος θέλει να σωθεί, είναι αναγκαίο πρώτα απ' όλα, να τηρεί την καθολική(ανοικτή σ' όλους, παγκόσμια, δεν εννοεί την Ρωμαιοκαθολική) πίστη.
2. Όποιος δεν την διαφυλάξει πλήρη και απαραβίαστη, χωρίς αμφιβολία θα χαθεί αιώνια.
3. Η καθολική πίστη λοιπόν είναι αυτή: Τιμούμε ένα Θεό εν Τριάδι, και την Τριάδα εν Μονάδι.
4. Χωρίς να συγχέουμε τα πρόσωπα, χωρίς να διαιρούμε τη Θεία Ουσία.
5. Γιατί άλλο Πρόσωπο είναι ο Πατέρας, άλλο ο Υιός κι άλλο το Πνεύμα το Άγιο.
6. Αλλά είναι μία η Θειότητα του Πατρός, και του Υιού, και του Αγίου Πνεύματος, ίση σε δόξα, συναιώνια σε μεγαλοπρέπεια.
7. Ότι είναι ο Πατέρας, είναι και ο Υιός, και το Άγιο Πνεύμα.
8. Άκτιστος (αδημιούργητος) ο Πατέρας, άκτιστος ο Υιός, άκτιστο και το Άγιο Πνεύμα.
9. Άπειρος ο Πατήρ, άπειρος ο Υιός, άπειρο το Άγιο Πνεύμα.
10. Αιώνιος ο Πατέρας, αιώνιος ο Υιός, αιώνιο το Άγιο Πνεύμα.
11. Και όμως δεν είναι τρεις αιώνιοι, αλλά ένας αιώνιος.
12. Όπως δεν είναι τρεις άκτιστοι, ούτε τρεις άπειροι, αλλά ένας άκτιστος και ένας άπειρος.
13. Παρομοίως, παντοδύναμος είναι ο Πατήρ, παντοδύναμος ο Υιός, παντοδύναμο το Άγιο Πνεύμα.
14. Και όμως δεν είναι τρεις παντοδύναμοι, αλλά ένας παντοδύναμος.
15. Έτσι Θεός είναι ο Πατέρας, Θεός ο Υιός, Θεός το Άγιο Πνεύμα.
16. Και όμως δεν είναι τρεις θεοί, αλλά ένας Θεός.
17. Έτσι Κύριος είναι ο Πατήρ, Κύριος ο Υιός, Κύριος το Άγιο Πνεύμα.
18. Και όμως δεν είναι τρεις Κύριοι, αλλά ένας Κύριος.
19. Γιατί, όπως μας υποχρεώνει η χριστιανική αλήθεια να αναγνωρίζουμε το κάθε Πρόσωπο να είναι Θεός και Κύριος αφ' εαυτού Του.
20. Έτσι και η καθολική θρησκεία μας απαγορεύει να λέμε ότι υπάρχουν τρεις Θεοί και Κύριοι.
21. Ο Πατήρ δεν έχει φτιαχτεί από κανέναν: ούτε έχει δημιουργηθεί, ούτε έχει γεννηθεί.
22. Ο Υιός, είναι μόνο του Πατρός. Δεν είναι κτιστός ούτε δημιουργημένος, αλλά γεννημένος.
23. Το Άγιο Πνεύμα είναι του Πατρός. Δεν είναι κτιστό ούτε δημιουργημένο, ούτε γεννημένο, αλλά εκπορευόμενο.
24. Έτσι υπάρχει ένας Πατήρ, όχι τρεις Πατέρες. Ένας Υιός, όχι τρεις Υιοί. Ένα Άγιο Πνεύμα, όχι τρία Άγια Πνεύματα.
25. Και σ' αυτή την Τριάδα κανείς δεν προηγείται και κανείς δεν έπεται, κανείς δεν είναι μεγαλύτερος ή μικρότερος (από τον άλλο).
26. Αλλά καθ' ολοκληρία τα τρία πρόσωπα είναι συναιώνια και ίσα μεταξύ τους.
27. Έτσι ώστε σε όλα τα πράγματα, όπως έχει ειπωθεί παραπάνω, η Μονάδα εν Τριάδι, και η Τριάδα εν Μονάδι πρέπει να λατρεύεται.
28. Όποιος θέλει να σωθεί, έτσι πρέπει να σκέπτεται για την Τριάδα.
29. Επιπλέον είναι απαραίτητο για την αιώνια σωτηρία, να πιστεύει σωστά στην ενσάρκωση του Κυρίου μας Ιησού Χριστού.
30. Γιατί η ορθή πίστη είναι αυτή που πιστεύουμε και ομολογούμε, ότι ο Κύριός μας Ιησούς Χριστός, Υιός του Θεού, είναι Θεός και άνθρωπος.
31. Είναι Θεός από την ουσία του Πατέρα Του, γεννημένος πριν από τους κόσμους. Και άνθρωπος από την ουσία της μητέρας Του, γεννημένος μέσα στον κόσμο.
32. Τέλειος Θεός, τέλειος άνθρωπος. Αποτελούμενος από ψυχή λογική και ανθρώπινη σάρκα.
33. Ίσος με τον Πατέρα όσον αφορά τη Θεότητα. Κατώτερος απ' τον Πατέρα όσον αφορά την ανθρώπινη φύση Του.
34. Όμως παρότι είναι Θεός και άνθρωπος, δεν είναι δύο, αλλά ένας Χριστός.
35. Ένας, όχι με μετατροπή της θεότητας σε σάρκα, αλλά με πρόσληψη της ανθρωπότητας από τον Θεό.
36. Ένας, ολόκληρος, όχι δια της σύγχυσης των ουσιών (της θείας & ανθρώπινης ουσίας), αλλά στην ενότητα του Προσώπου.
37. Γιατί όπως η λογική ψυχή και η σάρκα κάνουν έναν άνθρωπο, έτσι ο Θεός και ο Άνθρωπος είναι Ένας Χριστός.
38. που υπέφερε για τη σωτηρία μας. Κατέβηκε στην κόλαση. Την τρίτη μέρα αναστήθηκε από τους νεκρούς.
39. Ανελήφθη στους ουρανούς, κάθισε εκ δεξιών του Θεού Πατρός του Παντοδύναμου.
40. Από όπου και θα έρθει να κρίνει ζώντες και νεκρούς.
41. Στην έλευση του οποίου όλοι οι άνθρωποι θα αναστηθούν με τα σώματά τους
42. και θα δώσουν λόγο για τα έργα τους.
43. Κι αυτοί που έχουν έργα καλά, θα μεταβούν σε αιώνια ζωή, κι αυτοί που έχουν έργα κακά, σε αιώνια κόλαση.
44. Αυτή είναι η καθολική πίστη, την οποία αν δεν πιστεύει κανείς ειλικρινά και σταθερά, δεν μπορεί να σωθεί. Αμήν.

[Η Αγία Τριάδα](https://www.xn--mxalfbagtobsubcbnl9a.xn--qxam/%CE%A4%CF%81%CE%B9%CE%B1%CE%B4%CE%B1.html)

Comment: From http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2.iv.i.iv.html : "2 There is no authorized Greek text of the Athanasian Creed, since it was never adopted in the Oriental Church. There are several translations, which differ considerably. Usher gives a Greek version with many interpolations. Caspari (Vol. III. pp. 263–267) published for the first time two other Greek versions from MSS. in the Venetian Library of St. Mark and the Ambrosian Library of Milan."

Comment: @disciple: That is very interesting. Nice job finding that. I suppose what I found then is simply one translation of the Athanasian Creed in Koine Greek rather than the "authorized Greek text of the Athanasian Creed"

Comment: This is not Koine Greek, it's Demotic Greek